# If a person forgot whether they have already recited krias shema al hamita are they permited to say hamapil and should they do so?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, halacha-theory, hamapil, bracha-levatala

based on the idea of sufek derabanan lekula (a doubt in regards to a rabbinical ruling results in a leniency) and sufek d'orysa lechumra (a doubt on a Torah ruling results in a stringency) being that brachos (blessings) are mostly from the rabbis and a blessing said in vain (bracha levatala) is a Torah prohibition would this reasoning also include hamapil to say that when in doubt this bracha (blessing) should not be recited?

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different than any other blessing, which as you've already stated, in only Rabbinic?

Answer (score 3):

Hamapil is an independent bracha, not a bracha on the kriat shema.

Berachot 60b:

> הנכנס לישן על מטתו אומר משמע ישראל עד והיה אם שמוע ואומר ברוך המפיל חבלי שינה על עיני ותנומה על עפעפי ומאיר לאישון בת עין יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלהי שתשכיבני לשלום ותן חלקי בתורתך ותרגילני לידי מצוה ואל תרגילני לידי עבירה ואל תביאני לידי חטא ולא לידי עון ולא לידי נסיון ולא לידי בזיון וישלוט בי יצר טוב ואל ישלוט בי יצר הרע ותצילני מפגע רע ומחלאים רעים ואל יבהלוני חלומות רעים והרהורים רעים ותהא מטתי שלמה לפניך והאר עיני פן אישן המות ברוך אתה ה' המאיר לעולם כולו בכבודו

There is a chronologic juxtaposition.

KS al hamita is against mazikin, see Berachot 4b-5a

> א''ר יהושע בן לוי אע''פ שקרא אדם ק''ש בביהכ''נ מצוה לקרותו על מטתו אמר רבי יוסי מאי קרא {תהילים ד-ה} רגזו ואל תחטאו אמרו בלבבכם על משכבכם ודומו סלה אמר רב נחמן אם תלמיד חכם הוא אין צריך אמר אביי אף תלמיד חכם מיבעי ליה למימר חד פסוקא דרחמי כגון {תהילים לא-ו} בידך אפקיד רוחי פדיתה אותי ה' אל אמת:‏

A Talmid chacham doesn't need to say KS at bedtime.

Rashi says that anytime he reviews his mishna and learns, it is sufficient to protect him.

> שרגיל במשנתו לחזור על גרסתו תמיד דיו בכך

So KS is not a mitsva but a way to protect one from mazikin. This need no bracha.

So Birkat Hamapil is a Bracha as Birkot Hashachar, independent. Indeed, tje Gemara speaks about it in the same place it speaks about birkot Hashachar.

1) Your can say Hamapil without KS. Moreover, you can say KS after Hamapil, most minhagim do that. Poskim discusse that but there is no prohibition (see Magen Avraham OC 239 sk1, Rambam, Tosfot, Abudarham say one must say KS afer Hamapil). You can recite KS 1000 times if you want, there is also a minhag to say KS many times and falling asleep reciting it (Rema OC 239.1, source is Rabbi Zeyira in Yerushalmi).

2) If the question was if there is a safek i you already recited hsmapil. Out of birkat Hatora (see for instance Baer Heytev oc 47 sk1) and bircat hamazon (and and emet veyatsiv for people who don't say vayomer, berachot 20a, this is a problem of Safek derabanan lekula) all berachot are only chyuv miderabsnan. In case of safek, you cannot recite the beracha.

Rashi in Berachot 2a says that if you prayed Arvit before the night, you can use KS al hamita as mitsva. And Rashba says that people who were praying before the night did say a beracha before reciting KS al hamita, this Beracha is in the Siddur Rav Amram Gaon, and in Tosfot Rabbi Yehuda HaChasid. This is another beracha, not Hamapil.